# For loop and Random.Choice in python

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement

i am trying to write a for loop and if statement, my main aim is to print "Flee there is a bear when and if the random choice is red, i have tried many combination with no success

````
import random

Bee_Color = ["Red","Yellow", "Purple", "White"]

random.choice(Bee_Color)
        for x in random.choice(Bee_Color):
            
            if x == Bee_Color[0]:
                
                print("Flee!, There is a Bear!") ```
````

Comment: why use loop, it can easily done without loop

Comment: 1) Indentation is incorrect, 2) what's the purpose of the first call to random.choice, and 3) what's the purpose of the for loop?  The loop causes you to loop over the letters of the chosen color.

Comment: I can modified your code and its done without loop.

Comment: @Tamir Are you trying to have the program print "Flee there is a bear" **multiple times**, or is it just supposed to print once? If it's multiple times, does each print correspond to a different random choice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I point out your mistakes, there is no need to use a loop. Apply multiple combinations you clarify your code and what it can do.
**Here is your Code:**

```
import random
Bee_Color = ["Red","Yellow", "Purple", "White"]
random.choice(Bee_Color)#useless line of code
for x in random.choice(Bee_Color):#useless line of code
    print(x)# to see what your code can do
    if x == Bee_Color[0]:
        print("Flee!, There is a Bear!")
```

**your Codes output:**
With the help of `print(x)`

[image]

Now here is your **Modified Code.**

```
import random
Bee_Color = ["Red","Yellow", "Purple", "White"]
a=random.choice(Bee_Color)
print(a)
if a == 'Red':
    print("Flee!, There is a Bear!")
```

and here is your **output:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[random.choice()](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_random_choice.asp) is used when you have a sequence, like the Bee_Color list, and you want to randomly get one entry. This is how you would use `random.choice()` to get a random color, then check if the random color is red.

```py
import random

Bee_Color = ["Red", "Yellow", "Purple", "White"]

random_color = random.choice(Bee_Color)
print("Bee color is:", random_color)

if random_color == Bee_Color[0]:
    print("Flee!, There is a Bear!")
```

If you wanted to randomize `Bee_Color`, loop over it, and only alert when the color we're looping over is red, you could do something like:

```
import random

Bee_Color = ["Red", "Yellow", "Purple", "White"]

# random.shuffle() will change the position of "Red",
# so we need to store it in alert_color
alert_color = Bee_Color[0]

# Randomize the Bee_Color list
random.shuffle(Bee_Color)

for x in Bee_Color:
    print("Bee color is:", x)
    if x == alert_color:
        print("Flee!, There is a Bear!")
```